# Adding external hard drive to Xbox 360 causes problems

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, hard-drive

I purchased a new external hard drive for my Xbox and installed it. It completely wiped my hard drive and all progress on all games were removed. Now it is having trouble turning on...it stays on the loading screen and is not an internet connection problem. I've tried restarting it, taking out the hard drive, replacing the hard drive, and other troubleshooting methods found via the internet but with no avail. A few times the device has turned back on and allowed me to play, but all the game play prior to the installation of the hard drive is gone. Is there any way to fix this problem and/or retrieve lost game play?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker of mine had a similar problem when he tried to configure a Toshiba external for his Xbox. After configuring, his whole HDD was moved to the external, but he couldn't access anything on there. We ended up downloading his Live profile to the HDD and after that he could access everything on the external. Was this external drive for Xbox, or was it just a regular USB external? Do you still have profiles, themes, gamer pics, ect.? Were the files deleted immediatly after configuring the external? Did you check the external drive to see if anything was moved to there? When it stays on the loading screen, do you end up shutting it off, or does it shut off on its own? Get back to me and I'll try to offer some solutions

Comment: It was an Xbox hard drive...all the problems started when I hooked it up. There's nothing on the actual hard drive (except when the Xbox allowed me to play a couple of times)...my gamer info is still on there, all my accomplishments are still there, but all game play is lost. I end up shutting it off because it will simply stay on the loading screen until I turn it off.  Every once in a while it will let me play on it and all my game play from after the incident is still there, but nothing old. My Xbox memory says it has nothing on it...like it was wiped clean.

Answer (score 0):

Eject the disk tray while turning it on, also remove any other USB devices.
Look in the system storage while signed in to your profile and look for any save files in the game directory if you get it running.
Another possibility is to plug a controller in and turn on the Xbox from the controller while holding "Left trigger(L2) along with the "Y" button. This resets the display of your Xbox.
If you are using a cable with a high definition switch, turn it to basic.
I can't comment as yet to question, although if you were using a transfer cable, it most likely wiped the other drive. But I'm pretty sure you mean USB when you say external. Also, depending on the drive, some HDD(Including Xbox ones) take a while to load because of dust and clutter of information on the HDD.